# Choice question about formation of triangle having its sizes in integral number of inches

Tags: combinatorics

1. In how many ways, can we form a triangle having each of its sides an integral number of inches, greater than n and not greater than 2n?

   1a) How many of these will be isosceles triangles and how many
   equilateral triangles?

My attempt to answer 1) We have to select 3 numbers out of the numbers n + 1, n + 2,...,2n. Repetitions are allowed. Order is not important.

We cann't use here 2n! [Can we use it?]

My answer to 1a) Isosceles triangles = $n^2 - n $ ,equilateral triangles= n

My answer to 1) $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$

Comment: For this kind of problems, the main guideline is to answer the questions: is the order important? Are repetitions allowed?

Comment: It may be a good idea to answer the second part before the first. The number of equilaterals is just the number of ways of picking one number from that set. The number of isosceles is the number of ways of picking the repeated number times the number of ways of picking the other number. Then the number of other triangles is the number of ways to choose three numbers from that set. What this has to do with "chance" or "sensible logic" is beyond me.

Comment: Why using inches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We select the sides of the triangle from the set
$$n+1, n+2, \dots, 2n.$$

It's important to notice that we do not have to worry about the existence of any triangle. That is, in the extreme case we would have two possibly shortest edges and one possible longest edge, so a triangle with sides $n+1, n+1, 2n$, and the triangle inequality is still satisfied. This would only be a problem if we allowed sides of length $n$.

Firstly, let us assume that all possible selections of triplets form a triangle. Then, we have three cases:

1. each side has different length,
2. exactly two sides have the same length,
3. all of the sides are of equal length.

In the first case, we need to select three elements from a set of $n$ elements without repetition. So, the answer here is
$$\binom{n}{3} = \frac{n!}{(n-3)!n!}$$
In the second case we need to select two different elements from the set of $n$ elements and we can assume that we select the length for two equal-length sides first, and the length of the remaining side second. So, the answer here is
$$n\cdot(n-1)$$
In the final case, we select a single number from the set of size $n$, so we have just $n$ cases.

Collecting our answers, the total number of triangles is $$\binom{n}{3}+n(n-1)+n.$$

Note that in the second point we calculated the isosceles triangles and in the third point we calculated the equilateral triangles, so we have

- $n$ equilateral triangles
- $n(n-1)+n = n^2$ isosceles triangles, because every equilateral triangle is also isosceles.

Comment: Much as I wrote in my comment. But I was hoping to get OP to do some of the work.